# Make Python Print and Calculate Pay

Tags: python

Just my first question on SU.

I have my code underneath me, the final output needs to read "Pay: #"

Here is my error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on line 3

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")  
rate = 2.75  
pay = rate * hrs  
print ("Pay: (pay)")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `print ("Pay: {}".format(pay))`

Comment: The error comes up as this:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on line 5

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to multiply string which is a sequence of characters with float value.

You need to convert string to either float or int.

```
hrs = int(input("Enter Hours:"))
rate = 2.75
pay = rate * hrs
print ("Pay: {}".format(pay))
```

If the rate value, rate was an integer then this would multiply string `rate` times and returns resultant string.

Example:

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:") # if you input 5
rate = 3
pay = rate * hrs
print(pay) # prints 555
```